# What's a simple example of jQuery UI Autocomplete returning non-local results on AppEngine

Tags: jquery-ui, google-app-engine, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement a jQuery autocomplete search bar to be hosted on Google AppEngine (GAE). I have seen posts indicating that if I wish to use a remote source, I must filter the results myself. If I store the list in the script as an array, if filters correctly, so  I have also tried converting the large server-side JSON array returned from GAE to a local client array in order to avoid the need to manually filter. Neither try has worked.

What is the easiest way (for a jQuery/.js beginner) to get filtered non-local results?

This was my attempt to use the regex example provided in the jQueryui docs, and other examples posted on SO. If I type 'c' in the search bar, my dropdown list only shows and returns the letter c.

GAE .py code:

```
class Search(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = ["chickenpox", "chlamydia", "cholera" ]
        tags = json.dumps(data)
        self.response.out.write(tags)
```

template code:

Note: `'/search'` directs to the GAE server handler that returns the json data.

```
<script>
var availableTags = '/search';

$(function() {                          
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( availableTags, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
        },  
    minLength: 1,
     select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#user_input").html('Selected: '+ ui.item.value);
                var entry = ui.item.value;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Below was my attempt to convert `availableTags` to a local array so that autocomplete would filter the results itself.
Is this kind of hack/workaround even possible? If not why not?

```
var availableTags = '/search';
var new_local_array = $.parseJSON(availableTags);
```

Which method should I try and how? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `availableTags` just contains a string (`"/search"`). You haven't actually made an AJAX request to get the data back.

If you don't want to do the filtering on the server, I'd recommend making an AJAX request to retrieve the information, then configuring the autocomplete widget with that data:

```
$.getJSON('/search', function (data) {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) { ... }
    });
});
```

Basically what we're doing here is asking the server for the array of possible matches. When we get that array, we initialize the autocomplete widget with it. This will allow the widget to do all of the filtering for us.

Comment: this was super easy to fix for the client side filter.  i'd still love to see an example of the server side call with GAE.

Comment: @DLB: Basically you'd take the term the user searched for as a parameter to your method and filter the array based on that parameter.

Comment: Any idea how I post the result back to GAE? I want to use the user's input as a variable to then call the page corresponding to the disease listed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DLB: You would typically do this by posting a `form` (either traditionally or via AJAX)

Comment: I was trying to use a jquery method at first, but ended up going with a form. Thx.